# Returning An Object Created In A Native Function to a Java Method

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm a little confused what happens to an object created in a native function and is then returned to the calling Java method. For example, I have the following Java POJO:

```
public class Thing{
    private int valueOne = 0;

    public int getValueOne(){
        return valueOne;
    }

    public void setValueOne(int value){
        valueOne = value;
    }
}
```

And I have a native method that creates a Thing object and returns it :

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
create_thing(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj){
    /*
     Code ommitted that gets methodID of Thing's default constructor.
     */
     jobject result = (*env)->NewObject(env, thingClass, constructorID);
     return result;
}
```

An finally I have some Java method that calls create_thing():

```
public Thing createThing(){
    Thing thing = create_thing();
    thing.setValueOne = 2;
    return thing;
}
```

According to the JNI specification a call to NewObject (made in `create_thing()`) will return a LocalReference to an object, in this case a Thing. The `create_thing()` function returns the object immediately and in the case where it's called by a Java method as done in `createThing()` the LocalReference is deleted.

My question is, although the LocalReference is deleted does the object Thing still exist (because it is assigned to `thing` in the `createThing()` method)?

Am I correct in my understanding that the LocalReference is automatically deleted yet the object, provided it is assigned to a filed in the Java code remains in existence?

Furthermore, if the returned Thing were *not* assigned to a field then it would be marked for garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have it about right.

There is a difference between an object and a JNI local reference. The JNI framework deletes all local references when a method returns. (You can delete any earlier if you wish.) Deleting a reference does not delete the object it references.

In a garbage collected system, objects are not marked for collection. Instead, during a sweep, they are marked for retention. So, any created Thing is retained if it is referenced by a live object. Sweeping begins at one or more live "roots", which include JNI local and global references.

Comment: I think I found what you are looking for: [A native method may return a local or global reference to the VM as its result](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#referencing_java_objects).